# Who is the man in the red jacket in this painting?

Tags: 19th-century, france, art, identification

This is a painting from near 1850 that depicts a (famous) French man, possibly noble, in a park, maybe Paris.

Is he a Minister? King? Military? Whoever he might be, I consider he is important, since the people around bow before him (the woman).

Can anyone tell me who this man is?

[image: 19th Painting]

[image: 19th painting whole]

**A closer look at the gentleman and the military guard behind**
[image]

Comment: Knowing the name and artist of the painting, and everything else you might know or suppose about it, would help considerably. Also why you suppose the man to be French rather than British.

Comment: the author's name is unsure, I believe it might be Spanish, when he lived in Paris, but there's no title

Comment: Then at least tell us **where** the painting is on public display, so that we can research it.

Comment: The painting is from a private collection, the author MIGHT be Germán Hernández Amores, a Spanish painter. I think it was a preparatory painting of another bigger painting yet not found (if ever got done). After a bit researching, might be titled "Escena en un parque" (Scene in a park)

Comment: Where did you get the image from?

Comment: @ConradTurner the painting is from 19th, around 1850, when the supposed author was in Paris (where I think it painted it). Anyway, there's no possible way to know whether George III was anywhere in France with his wife in his late ages of life. If only any of you guys manage to recognize this guy from any history book or another painting...

Comment: What are the dates of the presumed artist's visit to Paris? Might he have visited any other European capitals, including the minor German states, during the same time period?

Comment: And are those mountains, trees or tall buildings in the back?

Comment: Just to note, the "guard" behind does not appear to be a guard at all; I doubt the painter would have portraited the "guard" chatting between themselves while the public figure they were supposed to guard was in the middle of a crowd. If they were a guard, they would be looking straight ahead, or slightly away (each one to his side). Looks more some noble/officers following the main figure.

Comment: @LauraAS, I think you might have to change your attribution to Germán Hernández Amores.  I saw the GH 'signature' in the lower left corner but I have a number of objections. If the scene is in France it is probably 50 years earlier.  Fashion in the 1850's would demand crinoline-type dresses whereas the two female characters in the foreground wear empire dresses (even the same hat and same as the young girl).  The uniform of the two officers in the back are also distinctively first empire and this seems consistent with several other characters in the background (revolutionary bonnets).

Comment: @LauraAS.  It could however be a copy by GH of some earlier painting by a local French painter.  You'll agree that this is very far from the neoclassical style and subjects that GH will be later known for (more like David or  Ingres).  You probably know that young artists (GH would be in his mid 20s at the time) would improve their *technique* by copying other painters (in the Louvres for instance).  So that's the only way I can think of that would reconcile the signature and the subjects.

Comment: @AlainPannetier yes, i've come to the conclusion as well, after reading all your posts (I really appreciate), that it could be a copy or not a real life painting. Also have i thought about the idea of GH copying it from a museum, but is quite hard to determine which one.

Comment: @LauraAS, As for the model, I have this more to share.  The painting itself is 'pre-impressionist' (again very far from his later works in the Académie/Salon technique). See the play with the patches of sunlight on the ground, the chestnut trees, the dresses, the uniforms.  And GH was a student of Charles Gleyre.  Now who else were students of Charles Gleyre? Monet, Bazille, Whistler, Renoir and Sisley. So may be these artists also made some copies of the same earlier artist.  Once you get a list of names, researching might be easier.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I have a book that explains the author's life, and he was in Paris between 1850-1851, just one year, learning from his mentor Charles Gleyre as Alain Pannetier has told above

Comment: @LauraAS: If he was there as a student he very likely did spend time copying and recomposing existing works.

Comment: He looks a bit like [Napoleon III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_III), expect that he doesn't have a moustache.

Answer (score 14):

The reason there are errors you can't reconcile is that this is not painted from life. *This* is a lady of 1850.
[image: women's costume, 1850]
After this the hoop skirts only get bigger.

This is a gentleman of 1855, who wears trousers and a frock coat.
[image: man in frock coat, 1855]

The people you see here are from decades earlier. The gentlemen wear swallowtail coats with breeches and stockings. The women wear the Empire waist, soft white gowns, and spencer jackets, with long shawls off their elbows, not big triangular ones covering the upper body.

In short, your Spanish painter was painting a scene out of the Napoleonic period, or shortly thereafter. The supposed queen wears the high waist, but her hair is that of before the Revolution, afro curls powdered over, while the "king" wears a powdered wig that would suit even the 1770s.

This means, depending on how good the painter's research was, he could have stitched together reference materials that were not compatible. This could explain the sash being the wrong side, besides the anachronisms. The women are mostly dressed 1810, with the queen wearing what is not really a walking dress, and lacking a bonnet. I would say she and the king are copied out of more official portraits.

At this point, you can only guess at what he was attempting to portray with his linseed oil time machine.Locating the structure in the back (I believe it is a carousel) will tell you where, though the guardsmen tend to indicate France -- but maybe not Paris. This could be a fantasy of Louis XVIII going for a stroll -- it needn't connect well with reality.

My three cents' worth, from studying the era 1803-1816, and training in portraiture, is that the king lacks the jaw structure of either George or William IV. He isn't Hanoverian.

Comment: This is also what my mind was leading towards - but I didn't quite know how to quantify the reasons.

Answer (score 9):

This is a picture of King Louis XVIII of France. The coat he is wearing closely resembles that of the [*Gendarmes de la Maison militaire du Roi*](http://www.bertrand-malvaux.fr/p/5922/uniforme-de-grande-tenue-des-chevau-legers-de-la-maison-militaire-du-roi-restauration-modele-1814.html) during the First Restoration (red cloth, horizontal lace and black velvet on the chest, etc.) As for why the lace and epaulets appear silver rather than the regulation gold, this is perhaps an affectation of the king, or an artist's error.

[image]

To those hung up on the red, recall that since the time of Louis XIV the *Maison militaire du Roi* had two broad groupings, the *Maison bleue* and the *Maison rouge*, based on the color of their coats. In the latter, during both the First Restoration and the *Ancien Régime*, we find the *Mousquetaires*, the *Chevau-légers*, and the aforementioned *Gendarmes*.

The military figures (in bicornes with plumes) in attendance behind Louis XVIII are officers of the [*Gardes du corps du Roi*,](http://www.bertrand-malvaux.fr/p/7659/gardes-du-corps-du-roi-service-du-chateau-grande-tenue-1820-1830.html) a *Maison bleue* unit of the *Maison militaire du Roi*. The six (reduced to four at the start of the Second Restoration) companies of this unit were each identified by a distinctive color. Here this identifying color should be noticeable at the base of the plume, in the shoulder straps, and worked in to their waist sashes, but it seems unclear -- perhaps green, which would identify the company as that of the Duke du Gramont.

[image]

As for precisely dating the scene between 1815-1824, this would hinge on whether or not Louis's coat is indeed intended to be that of the *Gendarmes*, who along with several other *Maison* units were dissolved at the start of the Second Restoration. It would be odd for the king to wear the uniform of a disbanded unit, as this was a disagreeable act to many in the French nobility since they lost position and prestige.

Comment: Nice work. I added a couple of links to enhance your research.

Comment: Thank you Pieter. The photo is of the _Chevau-légers_, but it gives an idea of the period style (esp. the red). And note that the Titeux plate shows the _Gardes du corps_ in full dress coat, and the painting in question the more casual "walking out dress" version (also with bicornes not helmets).

Answer (score 5):

A more likely possibility than General Colbert is [King William IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_IV_of_the_United_Kingdom) with his (much younger) wife Adelaide. They married in July 1818. Even after his ascension in 1830 William was known to walk around London and Brighton unaccompanied by guards <s>, as here</s>.

However the issue of the sash being worn on the wrong shoulder occurs again, and whether he was in the habit of making these walks in military dress I cannot determine.

**Update**: It is worth noting that the facial features as painted much more closely resemble William IV than General Colbert, who appears to have retained his slim facial features until his death.

In the British Army of this time (early to mid-nineteenth century) the red sash was simply an emblem of rank, with sergeants wearing it over one shoulder and officers over the other. However the references I have found to "the knot" placement seem to be opposite to how William IV is wearing it in [his official portrait here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_IV_of_the_United_Kingdom#/media/File:William_IV_crop.jpg) (as I presume the monarch's rank is not sergeant).

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought. General Colbert in his military dress does not wear the Napoleonic hat, the triconio, as depicted. However, as possible as William IV might seem, I think he died earlier than the visit of the possible author to Paris, considering that it was painted during his ages there. Also, he's indeed accompanied by his guards, in the whole painting is, but what i posted is a cut image of the whole, since I'm was only interested in knowing who he is. I'll upload the whole one

Comment: Not a french guy.

Comment: [I'll repeat the same commentary I've asked to another guy here.]         I'm curious. What makes you so confident believing he might be a King (!!!) and British? Because all I know of the author is that he was in France for a certain period. So, how come he could possibly paint this George III "in situ" or not (I mean, as a copy)? What were the odds of this (poor, maybe ?) Spanish author to paint this and him?

Comment: @LauraAS: As Conrad Turner has pointed out, the uniform looks distinctly British. The facial features resemble William IV fairly well and more closely (to me) than George III. Also it is certainly customary to bow when in the royalty's presence, when- and where-ever that might occur, but I recall no such tradition for non-royal ranks in the nineteenth and late eighteenth centuries. Further, to my eye at least the woman appears significantly younger than the man, which agrees with the facts for King William IV and Adelaide.

Comment: and the guards in the back seem as well British? Because at least, they appear not to be of the same range as the elderly man. Even their uniforms are quite different.

Comment: If the King and Queen walked about unaccompanied by guards, the men in French-looking uniforms behind the VIP man and woman could just be other random park-goers, not their bodyguard.

Answer (score 3):

Visually I think the Louis XVIII hypothesis is good, given the facial and corpulence high similarity, but also his spouse high similarity:

[image]
[image]

Below, the Queen Marie Josephine de Savoie(the facial resemblance of his spouse):

[image]

However, the comment below is stating (contrarilyy to one of the other answers depicting the red uniform as a French one) that the original uniform is British: In which case that would be a visual resemblance only.

Comment: Very unlikely IMO.  The hair is different and all the piece of clothing point to a period between between 1800 and 1820.  And this is a British uniform.

Answer (score 1):

The only French unit I am aware of that wore red uniforms was the [*Red Lancers*, Second Regiment of Light Horse Lancers of the Imperial Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2e_r%C3%A9giment_de_chevau-l%C3%A9gers_lanciers_de_la_Garde_Imp%C3%A9riale). The uniform *might* be that of a Red Lancers officer, but the painting doesn't give enough detail to be sure of much besides the colour.

The red sash and impression of a distinction on the left breast **might** be that of the [Grand Cross of the Legion of Honour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Honour) as shown [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/L%C3%A9giond%27HonneurGrades.png), except that the sash is being worn incorrectly; while the sash of a Red Lancer is worn on the left shoulder that of the Legion of Honour Grand Cross is worn on the right shoulder. Military officers **never** get this wrong, but painters might.

The most distinguished member of the Red Lancers in the decades following Waterloo was [Pierre David de](http://www.napoleon-series.org/research/commanders/c_colbert.html) [Colbert-Chabanais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_David_de_Colbert-Chabanais), who commanded the regiment from their creation in 1811 through the Russian campaign and into 1813, until promoted General de Brigade and then General de Division. After serving as Inspector General of Cavalry from 1826, he was made a peer of France in 1838, Grand Cross of Legion of Honour in 1839, and lived until 1853. This *might* be the gentleman in your painting, though [portraits](http://s46.radikal.ru/i111/0907/11/ec5026aec019.gif) [of](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral_Pierre_David_Edouard_Colbert_de_Chabanais.jpg/220px-G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral_Pierre_David_Edouard_Colbert_de_Chabanais.jpg) General Colbert never show him wearing the uniform of a Red Lancer, despite his apparent fondness for the uniform on the battlefield, **[Update]** and suggest that he retained his slim facial features until his death.

Comment: I wouldn't go on the color of the jacket of the aristocrat for determining the country. The man's jacket could be red just because he likes the color. But I agree that it shows some resemblance to a British uniform. Did George III ever visit France?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is almost certainly one of the restored Bourbon monarchs, either [Louis XVIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XVIII_of_France), [Charles X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_X_of_France), or [Louis Phillippe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Philippe_I). If the timing is correct then it would probably have to be Louis Philippe. By dress and appearance it looks much more like Louis XVIII of France.

The emblems he wears are not fully recognizable, but appear to possibly be the  Order of the Holy Ghost with the Toison D'or, the Order of the Golden Fleece, suspended directly below it. If correct, this would definitely point towards a king, particularly Louis XVIII.

(Voters notice that I was the first one to identify him as Louis XVIII.)

Comment: The uniforms of the soldiers nearby indicate that he's French, despite his red jacket.

Comment: @jjack Uh, right. All of my suggestions are French men. What is your point?

Comment: I mean I agree.

Comment: @TylerDurden The point is that several of the other answers assert quite confidently that the person in question is English. You did read the other answers before posting, right?

Comment: Except that none of the French kings you name have this face.  Not even Louis XVIII - and surely not Louis Philippe of Charles X.

Comment: Cornwallis is much more likable, agreed with the non resemblance of the others too

Answer (score 0):

The two officers behind the man in red look like they are wearing French Gendarmerie uniforms. Also, are those mountains in the back? I'm not sure the guy is English, despite his red jacket. The soldier in the far back wears a heat with a red hackle. The French Garde Republicaine wears similar hats with red hackles.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/French_Republican_Guard_Bastille_Day_2007_n4.jpg/340px-French_Republican_Guard_Bastille_Day_2007_n4.jpg

Comment: Quite interesting but not an answer.

Comment: Should've put it in a comment, but I forgot and then I couldn't delete it any more.

Answer (score 0):

1/ About the spouse of Louis XVIII : she died (in England, 1810) some years before her husband turned a French monarch !

2/ This French king was very close to his niece-in-law and niece, the daughter of Marie-Antoinette: Marie-Thérèse, duchesse d'Angoulème, aged 35 years when the french Bourbon monarchy was restored...

3/ the hats of the attendants are mainly "bicornes" with "plumet blanc" (bicorn with white plume) more an English "fashion" in regimental wearing, I guess...